# add occurences of the values of a list in another list

Tags: python

I am trying to find the add together the values of a list that are matching a value from another list. My logic is the following:

for all the values in list1, count how many times each values of list1 are in list2, add them together and append them to a dictionary.

my current code is not giving me what I am expected and I am failing to understand why.

```
  list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
  list2= [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5]

  count = dict()
  for i in list1:
     if i in list2:

     count[i] = sum(i in list1 for i in list2)

  else:
     count[i] = 1


 print(count)
```

As a result I get this:
{1: 11, 2: 11, 3: 11, 4: 11, 5: 11}

and I am trying to find: 
{1:3, 2:3, 3:2, 4:2, 5:1}

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2= [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,5]

count = {i:0 for i in list1}
for i in list2:
    if i in list1:
        count[i] += 1

print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Chao Peng, I spent so many hours and could not figure it out. I appreciate it.

Comment: You @LeLionJaune are welcome! I'm new to this community, could you let me know how to get my answer accepted?

Comment: i think that the answers get upvoted by others depending on good, thoughtful and relevant they are. not sure if it gets formaly accepted. thank you again for your help!